# 'String or binary data would be truncated' fix isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

So this is an old question that has been asked many times here, but the obvious solution isn't working for me. I have a query that reads:

```
INSERT Table1
(
    schoolName
)
VALUES
(
    <cfqueryparam value="#schoolName#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="50">
)
```

When running this query, I was getting back the 'String or binary data would be truncated' error that's been reported here dozens of times. I looked at the 'Design' option for my table and the maxlength for schoolName was 20, while the value I was trying to insert was of length 22. So in what I thought was an easy fix I simply ran:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN schoolName VARCHAR(50)
```

However I ran this query again, and got the same error! Is there anything else I need to do or anything dumb I am missing? Could it be a caching issue? From what I can tell, the error is saying that I'm trying to insert a string with a length larger than the column is set to allow, and therefore one (of the many) solutions is to expand the max column length.

Comment: The cfqueryparam tag is how ColdFusion binds variables and protects the database from SQL injection. So the tag is being used properly, with the value of the variable 'schoolName' being inserted into the table.

Comment: What happens when you try it not using ColdFusion?

Comment: Yes, this is a cold fusion issue not a Sql issue.  (Basically Dan's point).  do an sp_help on the table name to confirm that you did change the length to 50 (confirm the change was accepted).  One more thing to confirm.  Cold fusion may look at the table size before you made the change.  It may think it is still the old, I assume smaller size.  You may need to cycle your cold fusion server in some way to look at the database again.

Comment: @DanBracuk lol I get fired. That question gets asked every time I post a coldfusion question here.

Comment: when you post questions that are based on multiple tools working together.  Each side you post the question on blames the other.  You just have to put up with those who give you flack and wait for those who give you help.

Comment: @MTHead Haha yeah, I'm not complaining, reading those comments always makes me laugh :)
Thank you for the suggestion regarding sp_help. Unfortunately the column length is set to 50, so the change did go through.

Comment: I see it as about 50/50.  About half the response I see floating around are as useful as RTFM.  Some people try to be helpful with some assistance then they get flamed for helping because they did not provide a complete solution to the problem only an incremental step to the solution.  My favorite is when they provide links to the manual the is poorly written and does not cover the question asked.

Comment: How about the recycle of the Cold Fusion server?  It may look at the database once and not with every sql execution.  Thus it may think the table still has the old smaller size.

Comment: *That question gets asked every time I post a coldfusion question here* @ConorBaumgart - In case you were not joking, I am pretty sure Dan was talking about basic troubleshooting steps ;-)  ie Confirm which side is the problem by temporarily removing CF from the mix. Does the same SQL work when executed directly in SQL Server? If not, you have your answer. Otherwise, the problem is on the CF side. If you have confirmed the latter, then like MT said, maybe CF is not picking up the metadata changes for some reason. So a recycle is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid making this mistake, but it happens so I'll post the answer for anyone in the future:

There is a trigger set on my Table1 that was inserting into/updating a Table1Log table. Since the Table1Log schoolName column was not altered along with the Table1 schoolName column, I was getting the same error as before. Once I altered the column on both things started working fine.

Comment: I'm glad I found your post - I made the exact same error with a trigger to back up a table on inserts. I enlarged the column size on the base table but not the backup table.

Comment: Haha glad this helped! I remember thinking "no one will likely ever see this, but just in case..." and I'm glad it helped 6 years later

Comment: That's often why I post answers on StackExchange - I tend to encounter really rare errors, often in convoluted situations with little or no public information on how to extricate myself from them. So I make sure there's now at least one source of info out there after I figure out a work-around. Then 5 years later, someone out there benefits from it... LOL. :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `maxlength` attribute in the `cfqueryparam` tag is a validation that simply throws an exception before even sending the query to the SQL Server when the string length exceeds the specified maximum.

In your case it passed and the `String or binary data would be truncated` message is an error caused by SQL Server. Check if the `schoolName` column in the `Table1` table was properly altered by your change.

On a side note, if you are fine with truncated data, you could always use:

```
<cfqueryparam value="#left(schoolName, 50)#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
```

This truncates your value if it exceeds 50 characters without causing an error - unless your table schema specifies an even lower max. length. In this case you would still see the same error message.

Comment: Agreed. It is a SQL Server error, so either a) the table was *not* altered OR b) CF is not picking up the changes (less likely, but possible)